# iOS UIAlertview clear text and disable OK

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm a bit new to iOS development, and right now am working on some simple UI-related stuff. I have a `UIAlertView` that I'm using at one point to allow the user to enter some text, with simple Cancel and OK buttons. The OK button should be disabled if the text field is blank.

I added to my `UIAlertViewDelegate` an alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton function, so the OK button would disable when there's no text, and I also set the `UIAlertView`'s `UITextField` to have `clearOnBeginEditing` true, so the previous text would be gone every time I displayed the alert. Each of these things works perfectly on their own. Unfortunately, it seems like the AlertView is checking whether or not to enable the OK button before the text field is cleared, so when they're put together it comes up enabled. Below should be about the minimal code needed to reproduce.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    textEntryBox = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [textEntryBox setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [textEntryBox textFieldAtIndex:0].clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
}
-(IBAction)functionTriggeredByOtherLogic
{
    [textEntryBox show];
}
-(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if(alertView == textEntryBox)
    {
        if([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] > 0)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So, ultimately, my question is this: am I doing something completely against the natural iOS way of doing things here? Is there a better way to do this? Should I just ignore the `clearsOnBeginEditing` property of the `UITextField`, and manually clear the Text property before showing the `UIAlertView`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the textfield delegate to self

```
[[textEntryBox textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self]
```

and implement this method :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setText:@""];
}
```

I'm also having a UIAlertView with a textField to fill-in in my app, and it works for me

Comment: Nope, still doesn't seem to make the UIAlertView recheck whether or not the OK button should be enabled.

Comment: ok. Generally, I manage my alertView with their title. So what you can try to do is to instantiate your alert in `-(IBAction)functionTriggeredByOtherLogic` (without using a class property, so every time your method is call, you create a new alertView). And in your `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` delegate, test the title of your alertView to know if it is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using an alert view for this is probably a bit much. It might be easier if you use the master-detail paradigm and just push a new view controller where you can enter your values.